# Elegant ruby function, need help cleaning this up so it looks like ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have to parameters:  name and age

```
def self.search(name, age)

end
```

If name is not empty/nil, then add it to the search expression.

If age is not empty/nil, then add it to the search expression.

if both are nil, return all.

So far I have:

```
def self.search(name, age)

   if name.nil? && age.nil?
      return User.all
   end



end
```

**Finding it hard to write this in a elegant way.**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
def self.search(name, age)
  conditions = {}
  conditions[:name] = name if name
  conditions[:age] = age if age
  User.find(:all, :conditions => conditions)
end
```

Comment: how could I support an OR if I needed to, like name='asdf' or age = 234

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what sort of search you're doing but I prefer to handle these sort of things in a scope.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  scope :by_name, lamba{|name| name.nil?? scoped : where(:name=>name) }
  scope :by_age, lamba{|age| age.nil?? scoped : where(:age=>age) }

  def self.search(name, age)
    User.by_name(name).by_age(age)
  end
end
```

It's a bit more code overall I suppose but it's more reusable and everything is in it's place.

Comment: I like scopes too, but doesn't "User.by_name(name).by_age(age)" do an AND?, e.g. a set then a subset of that (=AND)

Answer (score 1):

In Rails 3 you can do it like this:

```
def self.search(name, age)
  scope = User
  scope.where(:name => name) if name.present?
  scope.where(:age => age) if age.present?
  scope
end
```

Note the use of present? rather than nil? to skip empty strings as well as nil.

In the other comment you mentioned wanting to OR these conditions.  ActiveRecord does not provide convenient facilities for that; all conditions are AND by default.  You will need to construct your own conditions like so:

```
def self.search(name, age)
  scope = User
  if name.present? && age.present?
    scope.where('name = ? OR age = ?', name, age)
  else
    scope.where(:name => name) if name.present?
    scope.where(:age => age) if age.present?
  end
  scope
end
```